# java: not found when running Ant in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I am having issue running ant via Jenkins pipeline. I am getting the following error when running JenkinsFile.

```
Started by user xxxxxx
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/xxxxxx_workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
[xxxxxx_workspace] Running shell script
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.6.0) (Alpine 8.151.12-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
[Pipeline] withAnt
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[xxxxxx_workspace] Running shell script
+ ant -d -version
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ant_1_10_5/bin/ant: exec: line 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk_8u181/jre/bin/java: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withAnt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

My JenkinsFile is as follows:

```
node {
  stage('Test') {
    env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk_8u181'}"
    env.ANT_HOME="${tool 'ant_1_10_5'}"
    env.PATH = "${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.ANT_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    sh "java -version"
    withAnt(installation: 'ant_1_10_5', jdk: 'jdk_8u181') {
    //  echo "Test ant"
      sh "ant -d -version"
    }
  }
}
```

I have Java and Ant setup in Jenkins Global Tools Configuration

JDK Setup screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdMRv.png

Ant Setup screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQr7v.png

The filepath for JDK and Ant and can confirm there are available. Note I am using docker so /var/jenkins_home is mounted to /opt/jenkins but you can see 'sh "java -version"' works anyway in the console output

```
[root@jenkins jre]# ls -al /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk_8u181/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 centos centos 7734 Jul  7 16:06 /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk_8u181/jre/bin/java
[root@jenkins jre]# ls -al /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ant_1_10_5/bin/ant
-rwxr-xr-x 1 centos centos 11638 Jul 19 10:54 /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ant_1_10_5/bin/ant
[root@jenkins jre]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice

```
[xxxxxx_workspace] Running shell script
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
                       ^^^
```

But

```
line 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk_8u181/jre/bin/java: not found
                                                       ^^^
```

When you run `java -version` you are getting whatever is in the PATH.  In your actual compilation you are trying to execute java at a ***different*** specific path.  It is quite likely that path does not exist, based on the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am still investigating and I believe 1.8.0_151 is from the java within the Jenkins container.